Dishwasher fill hose area gunky?
Just looking for possible explanations on why the fill hose area on my GE dishwasher looks gunky? It is a soft kind of soapy like residue, why I don't quite understand given the fact that I believe this is where clean, hot water should be flowing into the dishwasher? It doesn't appear to be mineral buildup as it is so soft. Is it possible that during cycles, some spray is coming back out of this area causing it?
Just looking for an explanation, or possible fix, had to take the dishwasher out to diagnose the drain pump not working and noticed this.


That may be spray foam residue...?

It's possible, I would expect spray foam to be tougher though, as this wiped off fairly easily with a cloth, and there's no other such material in the housing under the counter where they would have used any spray foam.

Did you pull away the fill line to see what was behind?
